# Extract characters from end in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

File *1.txt* has the following contents

```
abc12345
zyx98765
qwerty$%
```

My desired output

```
12345
98765
rty$%
```

#### PowerShell Code

```
$data = get-content "1.txt"

$charcount = 5;
$output = @()
foreach($line in $data)
{
   if ($line.length -gt 250){ $output += $line.substring($line.length-$charcount, $charcount) }
}

$output
```

There isn't any output. Any ideas?

Comment: None of your lines contains more than 250 characters.

Comment: `if ($line.length -lt 250)`

Answer (score 0):

To get your example working (output the last five characters / remove the first three), use the following code:

```
$charcount = 5
@'
abc12345
zyx98765
qwerty$%
'@ -split "\r*\n" | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring($_.Length-$charcount) }
```

To get the actual example working:

```
$charcount = 5
$output = @()
Get-Content "1.txt" | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.Length -gt 250) {
    $output += $_.substring($_.length-$charcount, $charcount)
  }
  else {
    $output += $_ # Append any line <= 250 characters
  }
}
$charcount
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems with your code.

The first one is the `if` statement:

```
if($line.Length -gt 250) { ... }
```

None of your example strings are more that 250 characters in length, so nothing will ever happen.

If you remove the `if` statement, you end up with this:

```
foreach($line in $data)
{
    $output += $line.Substring($line.Length - $charcount, $charcount)
}
```

This will work great for your current examples, but if you ever pass in a string that's less than `$charcount` characters in length, you will encounter an error, since `$line.Length - $charcount` is less that zero.

You can get around this with:

```
foreach($line in $data)
{
    if($line -ge $charcount) {
        $output += $line.Substring($line.Length - $charcount, $charcount)
    } else {
        # Line is less than $charcount long, return full string
        $output += $line
    }
}
```

Or, compounded into a single statement as [suggested by PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676026/extract-characters-from-end-in-powershell/39677254?noredirect=1#comment66655060_39677254):

```
foreach($line in $data)
{
    $output += $line.Substring([Math]::Max($line.Length - $charcount, 0))
}
```

Comment: `$line.Substring([Math]::Max($line.Length - $charcount, 0))`

Comment: @PetSerAl Also an option